# page number in pdf converted from html - pdfkit, python/django

Tags: python, html, django, render, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit with python/django to convert rendered html to pdf. How can page numbers be added in the pdf liike page 1 of 4.
I am converting html to string then passing it to from_string method of pdfkit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `options` should allow for creation of page numbers as follows:

```
options = {
   'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
   'footer-right': '[page]'
   }
pdfkit.from_string('Hello World', 'out.pdf', options=options)
```

According to  PDFKit's documentation you can use all of [wkhtmltopdf's options](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt)

Answer (score 25):

To add to the above anwser

```
  options = { 
      'margin-bottom': '0.75in', 
      'footer-right': '[page] of [topage]',
     }  
pdfkit.from_string('Hello World', 'out.pdf', options=options)
```

Will give the output **`1 of 2`**

the following are the other variables can be substituted.

- [page]       Replaced by the number of the pages currently being printed
- [frompage]   Replaced by the number of the first page to be printed
- [topage]     Replaced by the number of the last page to be printed
- [webpage]    Replaced by the URL of the page being printed
- [section]    Replaced by the name of the current section
- [subsection] Replaced by the name of the current subsection
- [date]       Replaced by the current date in system local format
- [time]       Replaced by the current time in system local format

Comment: Is it possible to modify the vertical positioning of the numbers? I have some text in the footer (2 lines of text). The page numbers are always at the top, but I would like to move them down (in line with the bottom line).

Comment: Yes, we need to play with margin.   In case your   text is static we can.  append before page number. try these options.

Comment: Is it possible to get the page number in the header?